# Vertically center inline-table element in a div

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically center a row of cells in an absolutely-positioned div. The height of the div is determined by an inline-block element immediately preceding the table.

I want to keep the `.title` out of the table because I'd like the entire menu to break to the next line if the screen isn't wide enough.

I've tried defining the height and the line height, applying padding, and giving the `.menu-box` element `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle`, but nothing seems to be working.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu-box">
        <h1 class="title">TITLE</h1>
        <table class="menu"><tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
        </tr></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
body,html {height:100%;width:100%;}

.container {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}

.menu-box {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
//  line-height:132px;
}

.title {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:132px;
}

.menu {
    display:inline-table;
    font-size:26px;
//  padding:40px 0;
}
```

And a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Q9nX/)

Comment: Don't use tables. my advice is to use ul, li :)

Comment: @Dhaval is correct. Tables should beused for tabular elements only.

Comment: Not that that has anything to do with the question you asked, of course. :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien you're right. That works. I just needed to apply it to both the `.title` and the `.menu`.

Comment: @Dhaval I wanted to keep the menu items in a single row in case the viewport width was smaller than the total width of the menu and the title. Should I use `div`s instead and use css to give it `display:inline-table` etc?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to vertically align a list. `line-height`, `vertical-align`, `padding`.

I personally use padding frequently, because it is a bit more dynamic, in my opinion, when percentages are used. I re-built your code  [***HERE***](http://jsfiddle.net/8Q9nX/6/) to show what I mean.